# Rails will_paginate endless scroll with an array that drops the first 3 items

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, will-paginate

I have a partial where I'd like to drop or not show the first three articles in the array because they are in a featured articles section. I also want the partial to use will_paginate w/ endless scrolling to load the next page of articles. The issue I'm facing is that when using `@articles.drop(3).each do |a|` and the next page goes to load, the array drops the next three articles again.

What's the best way to solve for this? My initial thought was an array within an array, where the first array drops the first 3 then the nested array returns all articles but I'm not sure how to do that?

Array code in partial:

```
<% @articles.drop(3).each do |a| %>
    <%= link_to a.source_url, :class => "flexRow" do %>
    <%= a.source %>
    <h3><%= a.title %></h3>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Index.js.erb

```
$('#article-index').append(' <%= j render("articles") %>');

<% if  @articles .next_page %>
  $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate(@articles, :previous_label => '', :next_label => '', :page_links => false) %>');
<% else %>
  $('.pagination').remove();
<% end %>
```

Index.html.erb

```
<div id="article-index">
<%= render 'articles' %>
</div>
```

UPDATE
This solution seems to work but doesn't feel elegant?

```
<% (@articles.current_page == 1 ? @articles.drop(3) : @articles).each do |a| %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
@articles[3..@articles.count]
```

This will drop the records held at index 0, 1 and 2, and return the remaining.

Comment: Thanks but this causes some funkiness with the pagination, not all articles appear.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You may do the following in your controller:</strike>

**EXAMPLE**

```
@articles = Article.where(...).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)

# Works only for the first HTML request
unless request.xhr?
  @articles.shift(3)
end
.
.
.
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js
end
```

Now, when you iterate over `@articles`, it would start from index 3, only for first time.

**EDIT**

```
<% (request.xhr? ? @articles : @articles[3..10]).each do |a| %>
  <%= link_to a.source_url, :class => "flexRow" do %>
    <%= a.source %>
    <h3><%= a.title %></h3>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Assuming the page size is 10.

Comment: Hmm, I get `undefined method `shift' for #<Article::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f9a3f30f9e0>` when trying that in the controller.

Comment: Thanks but that seems to miss the last page for some reason.

Comment: Sorry, that may be due to conditional mistake(The range needs to be applied when request is not **xhr**). I swapped the ternary condition. Check now.